# Python print formatted hex number in string

Tags: python

How to format number as hex inside string in print with efficient way? Basically I wanted to print a hex number in any position of string.

```py
a = [1, 2, 10, 30]

# this is working, but not very optimal, once it could have multiple entries
print("Setting new address: [%s %s]->[%s %s]", hex(a[0]), hex(a[1]), hex(a[2]), hex(a[3]))

# I was trying something like this, but didn't work like I wanted
print("Setting new address: %s" % [f'0x{x:02x}' for x in a])
```

My expecting result is

```
Setting new address: [0x01 0x02]->[0x0a 0x14]
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want this to handle larger `a` lists. What do you want it to *do* with a larger `a`?

Comment: Or if you only want to handle lists of length exactly 4, what did you mean by "not very optimal, once it could have multiple entries"?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to handle larger list than 4. For now I've just wanted to keep at 4. Later on the string could have more than 10x`%s` inside.

Comment: how should the string look if the list has 5 elements? 
how should the string look if the list has 10 elements?

Comment: It was just an example, but e.g. `a = [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 128]` and the string `Changes addr: [%s %s]->[%s %s] chnl:[%s]->[%s]`. Or the values could be glued from mupltile lists, but it's not case for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I will answer by myself...

```py
a = [1, 2, 10, 30]

print("Setting new address [%s %s]->[%s %s]" % tuple(["0x" + hex(x)[2:].zfill(2) for x in a]))
```

and the result is:
`Setting new address [0x01 0x02]->[0x0a 0x1e]`